# How to work with template choice in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material2

depending on the condition I want to display certain template.

if "this.showTemplateOrigDestReason = true" then it displays the template "#OriginDestinationReason" and so on...

```js
 changeTemplate(ruletagName) {
  
    console.log(ruletagName)
   if(ruletagName == 'OriginDestinationReason'){
     this.showTemplateOrigDestReason = true;
   }else if(ruletagName == 'inputList'){
    this.showTemplateInputList = true;
   }else{
     this.showTemplateOrigDest = true;
   }  
  }

}
```

```html
<ng-template #tagDescription >
  <mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list" *ngIf="!showTemplateOrigDestReason; else OriginDestinationReason " >
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let tags of descriptionTags" (click)="changeTemplate(tags.ruleName)">
       {{tags.nameTag}}
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</ng-template>



<ng-template #InputListTag>
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="30" >
   <h1>InputListTag</h1>
 </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #OriginDestinationReason>
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="30" >
   <h1>OriginDestinationReason</h1>
 </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #OriginDestination>
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="30" >
   <h1>OriginDestination</h1>
 </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to simply use `ruletagName` with `ngSwitch`.

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="ruletagName">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'tagDescription'"> ... </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'OriginDestinationReason'"> ... </ng-container>
    ...
</ng-container>
```

[Here's a full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqxs3p?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[ngIf]` directive provided by `Angular`

```
<ng-template #InputListTag [ngIf]="showTemplateInputList">
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="30" >
   <h1>InputListTag</h1>
 </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #OriginDestinationReason [ngIf]="showTemplateOrigDestReason">
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="30" >
   <h1>OriginDestinationReason</h1>
 </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #OriginDestination [ngIf]="showTemplateOrigDest">
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="30" >
   <h1>OriginDestination</h1>
 </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I need template #tagDescription to disappear and only get the template validated, it's possible?

Comment: can you please elaborate? which template you want to validate?

Comment: if user clicks the tags.nameTag [i] and it will be of type #inputList it will exude #InputListTag in place of #tagDescription

Comment: P.S. It's a better idea to use `ngIf` as `*ngIf` instead of square bindings.